How to know the Type of DevOps Agent in a Pipeline?
I have been trying to setup a CICD Pipeline for Business Central and would like to know in runtime what type of Azure DevOps Agent is being used to run the pipeline? (Azure Hosted vs On-Prem Hosted) as this will change the way the Build is done.
Please let me know if this is possible to achieve. So far I have implemented a logic where I check the name of the pipeline and if it starts with "self_hosted" then I know it is an on-prem installation and so.

You can use demands based on the user or system capabilities to specify which agent should run your pipeline or job.

You can use the value of the predefined variable "Agent.Name" to identify the agent type:

If using Microsoft-hosted agents, the value always is "Hosted Agent".
If using self-hosted agents, the value is the customized agent names when configuring the agents.

In certain situations, the self-hosted agents might have been configured with the same name (Hosted Agent) as the Microsoft-hosted agents. At this time, you also can use the value of the predefined variable "Agent.CloudId" to identify the agent type:

If using Microsoft-hosted agents, the value is a GUID.
If using self-hosted agents, the value is empty.

See below example as reference:
# azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- job: A
  strategy:
    matrix:
      WindowsPool:
        poolName: WindowsPool  # A pool of self-hosted Windows agents.
      LinuxPool:
        poolName: LinuxPool  # A pool of self-hosted Linux agents.
      MsHosted:
        poolName: 'Azure Pipelines'  # The pool of Microsoft-hosted agents.
  pool: $(poolName)
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - pwsh: |
      Write-Host "Agent.Name = $(Agent.Name)"
      Write-Host "Agent.CloudId = $(Agent.CloudId)"
      Write-Host "Agent.MachineName = $(Agent.MachineName)"
      Write-Host "Agent.OS = $(Agent.OS)"
      Write-Host "Agent.OSArchitecture = $(Agent.OSArchitecture)"
    displayName: 'Show Agent Information'


